# QRunnable and passing a Pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to pass a pointer (ImageInput) to the QRunnable::run() method. The compiler compiles and I get no errors. But when I try to use the variable in run(), the program crashes. Does somebody know where the mistake is?

Here is a minimum sample:

Function, where I'm creating the thread (actually only one):

```
bool framesource::MapRealToMat (std::vector<cv::Point3f> &PointVec)
{
cv::Mat TestMat = cv::Mat::ones(424, 512, CV_32FC1);
ThreadClass *Part1 = new ThreadClass(PointVec,&TestMat);
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(Part1);
}
```

Class, where I'am using the run() method:

```
class ThreadClass : public QRunnable
{

public:
    ThreadClass(std::vector<cv::Point3f> &PointVecInput, cv::Mat *ImageInput):
        PointVec  (PointVecInput),
        Image (ImageInput)
    {
    }


private:
    QMutex      mutex;
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> PointVec;
    cv::Mat* Image;
    void run();
}; 

void ThreadClass::run()
{
bool wait = true;
while(wait)
{
    if(mutex.tryLock())
    {
    //Do something with the image, example:
            cv::imshow("test",*Image);
            mutex.unlock();
            wait = false;
    }
}
}
```

The Pointer points at the aimMat, which should fill by 8 threads. And each thread work in a different image area. But actually I'm using only one thread and one AOI.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
cv::Mat TestMat = cv::Mat::ones(424, 512, CV_32FC1);
```

which defines `TestMat` as a local variable. Local variables go out of scope when the function returns. That means the `TestMat` object will be destructed and its memory will be reclaimed when `MapRealToMat` exits.

After the definition of `TestMa` you do:

```
ThreadClass *Part1 = new ThreadClass(PointVec,&TestMat);
```

Here you pass a pointer to the local variable to your class. The problem with this should be obvious after reading the previous paragraph. The pointer will, after the return of `MapRealToMat`, no longer point to a valid object.

The simple solution is probably to pass the `TestMat` object *by value* instead of using pointers.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. I have to wait for each thread. When I'am using QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone(); , it works fine.